# How do I get jquery's toogleclass to work? adding a class of "open" to my hamburger-menu.

Tags: javascript, jquery, hamburger-menu

The aim is to create a hamburgermenu that when "clicked" folds out adding a class of .open, while pushing the existing div down below, so that it would still be possible to see the content of this div even when the menu is open.

I have trouble getting jquery to work at all and am not sure where I have made a mistake.

If you do, please enlighten me, it would be a great help! I have tried several times with different tutorials.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".menuicon").on("click", function(){
        $(".menuoverview").toggleClass (".open");

    });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;

}

.header .menuicon {
display: flex;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;

}

.header .menuicon img {
  padding: 2%;

}

.header .logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 30%;


}

.header .logo img {
width: 130px;
height:auto;
padding: 1%;
margin-left: %;

}

/* This is the default class when the menu icon is not yet clicked. The // should of course be removed */

.menuoverview {
//height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

/*This is the class that should be applied when clicking on the menu icon */
.menuoverview .open {
height: auto;
overflow: visible;

}

.menuoverview {
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
display: flex;
}

.menuoverview .menuitem{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 5%;

}



.videobox {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.menuoverview {
 flex-direction: column;
}

.menuoverview .menuitem {
 align-self: center;
 padding: 1%;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=“resources/css/lasttry.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/lasttry.js"></script>
  </head>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="header">
  <div id="icon" class="headericon">
  </div>
  <div id="logo" class="headericon">
    <img src="resources/logo_3dinspo.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="menuoverview">
  <div class="menuitem">
    <h4 class=menuheader>header1</h4>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menuitem">
    <h4 class=menuheader>header2</h4>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menuitem">
    <h4 class=menuheader>header3</h4>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

JP

Comment: `.` isn't part of the classname is it? `$(".menuoverview").toggleClass(".open");` -> `$(".menuoverview").toggleClass("open");` (close as typo)

Comment: while using `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()` or `.toggleClass()`, the class name does not need a preceeding `.` (dot).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the dot in the toggleClass?

```
.toggleClass("open");
```

I don't think you need to specify that it is a class in this method, since it is already looking for a class name.

Quick codepen example: https://codepen.io/mkempinsky/pen/XxKNoe